# Algorithm to find largest weight path of a graph where weight is given by multiplication

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, monoid, python, semiring

So my problem is to find the longest path from a node to another node (or the same node) in a graph implemented with Networkx library.

I don't want to add the edges' weights but multiply them and take the biggest result. Obviously, passing only once by each node or not at all.

For example if I want to go from node 1 to node 4, the best result would be : 2 x 14 x 34 x 58

[Graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg15Q.png)
[image]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The multiplication isn't a problem. The longest weight multiplication problem can be transformed into a standard longest weight by addition problem by taking the $\log$ on all the edge weights

Comment: I believe if your graph has cycles that the problem is NP-hard, a la traveling salesman, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: Thank you but even if the graph has cycles, we can go trough a node only once.

Comment: I’m aware that you’re searching for paths through distinct vertices. The problem is that once there is any cycle in the graph, the path between nodes becomes non unique. Hence even though your interested in paths, the mere presence of cycles in the graph makes the problem NP Hard

Comment: Also, in general, questions about algorithms may be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com. The community there has more experts on algorithms